# MySQL delete from Memory table join InnoDB table

Tags: mysql, join, innodb, sql-delete, memory-table

My query is:

```
DELETE FROM abc_memory INNER JOIN abc USING (abc_id) WHERE x < y
```

and MySQL complains by saying:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN abc USING (abc_id) WHERE x < y' at line 1
```

In MySQL there's a limitation on neither joining a memory table with an innodb table nor deleting while joining two normal tables. But is there a limitation on deleting from a memory table while joining that with an InnoDB table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a `JOIN` in `DELETE`, you have to list the table names in the `DELETE` clause, to tell it which table(s) to delete from.

```
DELETE abc_memory
FROM abc_memory
JOIN abc USING (abc_id)
WHERE x < y
```

This will just delete from the `abc_memory` table. If you want to delete from both tables, change it to `DELETE abc_memory, abc`.

This is explained in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html):

> **Multiple-table syntax**
>
> ```
> DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE]
>     tbl_name[.*] [, tbl_name[.*]] ...
>     FROM table_references
>     [WHERE where_condition]
> ```
>
> or:
>
> ```
> DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE]
>     FROM tbl_name[.*] [, tbl_name[.*]] ...
>     USING table_references
>     [WHERE where_condition]
> ```

You either have to list the tables after `DELETE` or in a `USING` clause (this isn't the same as the `USING` option in the `JOIN` clause).

Comment: That's not true if joining two normal (InnoDB) tables. If you don't list any table name in DELETE clause, it will delete from the left table in join clause

Comment: It's a syntax issue, it has nothing to do with the type of table. Read the syntax description in the manual.

Comment: @Aliweb I've copied the syntax description.

Comment: You're right. I'm not sure why I have in my head that in the past I have successfully used the delete join syntax mentioned in the question. Thanks anyways.